# Use observer to update custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, module

I have created a custom attribute called price_incvat and, following the basic instructions [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/) mashed up with some answers found elsewhere on this site, I have tried to create a module that uses an observer to populate the attribute field in a product with the price of the product plus VAT (20%). I don't really know what I'm doing so of course it hasn't worked. Here's my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
         <cvnstore_IncVatAttribute>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
         </cvnstore_IncVatAttribute>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cvnstore_incvatattribute>
                   <class>cvnstore_IncVatAttribute_Model</class>
            </cvnstore_incvatattribute>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                  <observers>
                      <cvnstore_incvatattribute>
                        <class>cvnstore_incvatattribute/observer</class>
                        <method>incVatUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                      </cvnstore_incvatattribute>
                  </observers>
              </catalog_product_save_before>
           </events>
     </global>
</config>
```

And my Observer.php

```
class cvnstore_IncVatAttribute_Model_Observer
    {
        public function incVatUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
                $price = $product->getPrice();
                $product->setPriceIncvat($price*1.2);
            }
    }
```

I will be very grateful to anyone who takes the time to set me straight.

Comment: At what point are you are trying to update price_incvat after product admin save or on add to cart?

Comment: After admin save. We get a data feed from a wholesaler and I want this field to be populated when the product is loaded as part of the import.

Comment: Well, as you probably could have told me, I seem to be going about this the wrong way. Importing new product info (one of the imports only updates prices and stock levels) doesn't trigger the save_before event, or the save_after or any other of the events I have tried, so nothing is inserted to the price_incvat field. I feel another post coming on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help -

```
public function incVatUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $priceWithVat = $price*1.2;
    $product->setData('price_incvat',$priceWithVat);
}
```

Comment: If you try to re-save within `*_save_before` you should get a infinite loop

Comment: Ah, good point! Next time I will slow down and read...

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. I am going into the product record, making a small change, then saving the record and the field is still empty. Would I be better using the save_after event?

Comment: Got it. The problem was that I had defined the namespace with a fully lowercase name - cvnstore. When I changed it to Cvnstore and updated all the references to that in the relevant files, the code you have given worked. Thanks for your help. Now to see if reloading the product datafeed populates my price_incvat field. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Glad it helped! I think you should be ok with the datafeed based on the event you are grabbing, if not post a comment here.

Comment: Sadly not @AreDubya, see new post here (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71565/update-custom-attribute-when-product-data-updated-through-import?noredirect=1#comment94469_71565)