# Update custom attribute when product data updated through import

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, import, product-attribute

We import product data using a feed we get from a wholesaler - one full import a week that merges product data and a daily import that only updates price and stock data. I have created a custom attribute called `price_incvat` and I want this to be populated with the price plus 20% once the product data is updated by the import.

I tried to do this by creating an observer that would update the attribute on the `catalog_product_save_before` event (see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71495/use-observer-to-update-custom-attribute?noredirect=1#comment94319_71495)) without realising that this event would not be triggered by the import. I have tried to use the same code with various other events as listed [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events) but without success. I feel I have been barking up the wrong tree?

Can anyone suggest a better tree to bark up?

Comment: are you using magmi or the default  magento import?

Comment: I am using a module supplied by Stock in the Channel that imports their own datafeed.

Comment: Check for events fired by their module if they fire any and attach your observer there. another possible solution would be to modify their extension to update your attribute after it updates the price

Comment: Thanks. In their config.xml they attach an observer to sinchimport_model_import_after so I attached mine to that too. Doesn't seem to work. Is there a problem with my observer (see link to previous post above)?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, would that event only happen after the entire import, meaning that my observer would be useless at that point? Is there anywhere other than config.xml I could check for events?

Comment: Look through their source code and check if any after type of after save event is being triggered or you could dispach your own event. you may need to modify your observer functionality based on the data being passed in the event.  Check this link for details on dispatching your event. http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-dispatching-your-own-event-in-magento/

Comment: I wonder if you are solving this problem in a different way to how other might. Are you on a recent version of Magento and are you using the tax rules? There should be no need to store as attribute a value that a computer could theoretically calculate for itself.

Comment: The reason I need this as an attribute is that we are exporting a datafeed to Google using the SimpleGoogleShopping extension. Even if you set the store prices to show with VAT in the frontend the datafeed exports the ex VAT price, referencing the normal_price attribute. There is no price attribute including VAT that I can change this reference to, so I created one myself. If there is another way round this I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: @NathanielR I think I've found the function code that updates the product data, but it does so by issuing SQL commands using db_do(). Will adding an event to the function work as presumably the event would only fire once for the entire update?

Comment: Would it be possible to add the code to paste bin and link it back here so that i could get a better understanding to help you out ?

Comment: Sorry for delay in posting - I'm only in Thursdays and Fridays. The model that does the heavy lifting seems to be Sinch.php which I have put here (http://www.filedropper.com/sinch). My comments on what the relevant functions seem to be is here (http://pastebin.com/7tiBRPnx)

Comment: @NathanielR - just naming you in this comment because I didn't name you in the last comment and now I'm worried you won't know it is up.

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of these events

```
catalog_product_attribute_update_before //when attribut is updated
catalog_product_prepare_save //when product is saved
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried them now but no dice.

Comment: I doubt these two events would fire as the module is using SQL code to update the Database

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to go -

1. Extend the module from Stock in the Channel to calculate
   price_incvat and save that value in the SQL call.
2. Run a script after the import that calculates
   price_incvat and saves it.

If Stock in the Channel fires an event once at the end of the import, you could use an observer to handle triggering a script that would set price_incvat.

Extending the module and adding price_incvat  to the SQL would probably be the least amount of code, and you get the performance benefit of SQL.

Comment: Ideally the SQL option would be the way to go but I am finding it hard to understand the code in the relevant functions (see comment above posted today)

Comment: Pursuing option 2, I found a script elsewhere that I could modify to do the job and it works. I have my observer, now I just need the no doubt simple piece of code that it can use to fire the script. Tried googling it but no joy. Can you help?

Comment: Guess what. I just found the extremely simple way of exporting the inc VAT price through Simple Google Shopping that I completely missed in the documentation. I didn't need to do any of this. None of it. Deeply embarrassing. Thanks for all your help though, you and @NathanielR both.

Comment: Well, sometimes that happens! We have all been there. If you think the solution can be used by others, put it here as an answer and mark it accepted please.